# Domain/Range of a Contraction Mapping

Tags: functional-analysis

I have been given the following definition for a contraction mapping:

A self-map $T:X$-->$X$ defined on a metric space $(X,d)$ for which there exists a real number $0<a<1$ that satisfies $d(T(x),T(y))\leq a*d(x,y)$ for all $x,y$ in $X$.

My question is this: if we take the function $f:R$-->$R$ defined as $f(x)=.5x$, then $f$ is a contraction. But if we take this function over the domain $[0,1]$, for example, then the domain and codomain are no longer equal. With this new restricted domain, is $f$ no longer a contraction?

Comment: you can view $f$ as a map from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$. It just won't be surjective.

Comment: What if the function were $f(x)=.5x-1$ and $1<x<2$? Would it then still be a contraction by just calling the domain and codomain $R$?

Comment: The domain is not $R$ if $1 < x < 2$

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea behind the contraction mapping is to contract and more than likely takes the whole space to a single point under iteration.

For example your $f(x)=x/2$ will map the interval $[0,1]$ to the singleton zero under infinite iteration.

Thus the contraction does not have to be onto and better not to be for real applications.